# Correct form of verb after "A vast majority"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, passive-voice

What form of verb must be used after "A vast / good / large majority?"

For instance :

```
A good majority of libraries have OR has been replaced by the internet.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third person plural form - **have**

> A good majority of libraries **have** been replaced by the internet.

Think of it as replacing "A good majority" with "They" and see what makes sense. You wouldn't say "They has".